# Launch a .NET DLL from an ASP.NET page

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll

I'm working with a intranet website written in ASP.NET and need to be able to access a DLL that is installed on the user's computer. I can get it working if I'm hosting the site locally but when I try to access it from another machine it does not work. I realize this could be a dangerous tool to use but if you have a valid business purpose for doing this, is it possible?

I've looked around and there might be a way to use JavaScript to do this but I'm wondering if there is anything else.

To make it work locally I had to add AspCompat to the page so the first like looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" AspCompat="True" %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what valid use case would be acceptable to allow for this huge gaping security hole.

Comment: It shouldn't even be possible. Any modern web browser should have JavaScript entirely sandboxed. You'd have to have a signed applet of some sort, Java or XBAP. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Here's a valid business reason for doing this. I have an ASP.NET app that does basic accounting and credit card processing. I would like to offload the credit card portion to another software so I don't need to worry about cardholder data security and more importantly avoid undergoing the required PA-DSS audit which costs $10+k. I'm working with a company that has a software that makes this possible but you need to invoke their DLL to have their software pop up and handle the transaction. This is a nice solution because their app runs in IE and you can style it and is exactly what I need.

Comment: There aren't really any better ways to do this in order to be taken out of scope.

Keep in mind this will be accessing a DLL that is installed using an application on the user's machine. This is not for users who do not have the software already installed and would not be a public page.

Comment: The fact that this is going to access a dll that does credit card processing does not make this seem more valid.  It makes it more scary.  Remember:  If you can access that DLL from say... IE, so can anyone else.  Scary thought.

Comment: Also - Testing and maintaining this sort of solution, even if you do get it to work, is going to cost them a hell of a lot more than $10k for the audit.

Comment: That company had their application and DLL validated already and it passed and since they are the credit card processing company I think they will be required to keep up on the validation/maintenance of it. I do agree that it's a heck of a way to get around the issue but I don't know of any other ways around avoiding doing the audit yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with a valid reason, I'd find another way, like having them download an .exe.  Think of it this way.  Even if you REALLY needed to loan your car to someone, would you leave it at the mall unlocked with keys in the ignition all day until they could pick it up?  Because that's what you'll have if you find a way to change their security to allow this .dll execution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two options:

1: get a copy of the user machine's dll and include into your asp.net web application, via adding a reference to it. keep in mind that this dll will be executing from your web server machines, thus cannot access local resources on user's machines beyond what is available from a web browser.

2: rewrite your web application into a desktop application (windows forms, or WPF), and deploy it via ClickOnce or XBAP etc.

I don't think Javascript will allow you to invoke a dll in client local computer, unless of course you already have an ActiveX plugin or something installed.

Comment: Hmmm... so it sounds like an ActiveX might be the way to go here. Thanks hongliang.